# Getting error when try to upload IPA using Xcode 10.1 or application loader

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store

When I try to upload build it shows me error like:

**ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 11.4 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK or later, included in Xcode 9 or later. Further, starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later."**

I know I cannot upload build using old version of XCode. My project was build on Xcode 10.0 but when I try to upload using XCode 10.0 it give above mention error. But When I open project in XCode 10.1 it gives me lots of error due to swift version but I cannot fix because of timeline.

Inshort, 
**Successfully build on XCode 10.0 but failed in XCode 10.1** and appstore requires iOS 12.1 for upload which is available on in XCode10.1 I tried to make build from XCode 10.0 and upload using application loader of XCode10.1. But still getting error, Any Solution?

Answer (score 0):

Probable solution here would be building your app with the latest SDK available.
But downgrading the version of Swift to your desired one from settings in Xcode.
Please go to build settings of your target on latest Xcode & search for Swift Version. Then if may the latest one in the market so downgrade same to your expected one. So you will not get that much errors upon building

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to solve the problem I got solution that is as per appstore new rule they app should be build in iOS version 12.1 atleast. So I got iPhone SDK 12.1 folder from XCode 10.1 content folder and paste it to XCode 10 Content folder.
App uploaded successfully... :)